# Is there a way to override filetype syntax?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype

I have a `file.conf` that has jsonc data. I tried the following hints at the beginning of the file:

```
// vim: ft=jsonc
```

and

```
# vim: ft=jsonc
```

but it has no effect, the filetype is still set to `conf`.

I know I can give a command manually `:set ft=jsonc`, but how to make it work automatically?

NOTE: The file name cannot be changed.

Comment: Works for me. What do `:set modeline?` and `:set modelines?` say?

Comment: nomodeline, modelines=5

Comment: Then `:set modeline` to make it work.

Comment: Yes, this was it. Do you want to post an answer, or it is not worth it?

Comment: I'm actually writing one right now but it's really up to you to decide. PS: glad it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "hints" you put in files to set Vim options are called *modelines*. You can read about them in `:help auto-setting`, item 3, or `:help modeline` immediately below.

For modelines to work, the `modeline` option needs to be set and the `modelines` option will give the number of lines that are searched from the beginning and end of each file. These are documented in `:help 'modeline'` and `:help 'modelines'` (note the single quotes), respectively.

You can add the following line to your `vimrc` to enable modeline evaluation

```
set modeline
```

If your modelines are not within the first or last 5 lines of your files, you will also need to increase the value of `modelines`.